# Shell: echo Multi character string

Tags: scripts

Lets say I have strings like this:

```
/somefolder/andsubfolder/my_first_text.txt
/somefolder/andsubfolder/my_second_text.txt
```

and I want to create a loop to echo

```
my_first_text
my_second_text
```

After some research I found out that the `cut` command is not abled to do so. I think `awk` might be an option but I did not fully understand how to get it working properly on this example... so any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the simplest way is to use [string operators](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919). For example, if:

```
str="/somefolder/andsubfolder/my_first_text.txt"
```

then you can use somethink like:

```
str=${str##*/}
echo ${str%.txt}
```

But, you can still use `cut` with the help of `rev` (see `man cut` and `man rev` for more info):

```
echo $str | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d. -f 2- | rev
```

And the solution using `awk` is:

```
echo $str | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | awk -F. '{$NF=""}1'
```

Comment: awesome. thank you. returns: my_first_text.txt ... any way to further cut of the ".txt"? And can you give me a hint how the syntax for the first example works?

Comment: @Joschi I updated my answer. If you want to cut `.txt`, you can use for example: `echo ${str##*/} | awk -F. '{$NF=""}1'`

Comment: @Joschi Just now I sow in your question that you didn't want `.txt` at the end. So, I just edited again my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using any external programs such as cut or awk, you can sort-of concatenate bash string operators e.g. if `str="/somefolder/andsubfolder"` then

```
str="${str##*/}"; echo "${str%.txt}"
```

removes first the leading path component (longest prefix matching `*/`) then removes the `.txt` suffix (shortest suffix matching `*.txt`)

You could also do

```
str="${str##*/}"; echo "${str%.*}"
```

to remove any single `.*` suffix instead of just `.txt`

Answer (score -1):

try this out shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

abc=/somefolder/andsubfolder/my_first_text.txt
my_file=$(echo $abc | awk -F/ '{print $4}')
echo "$my_file"
```

this will sure help you.

Comment: Have you tested your "solution"?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

abc=/somefolder/andsubfolder/my_first_text.txt
my_file=$(echo $abc | awk -F/ '{print $4}')
echo "$my_file"sorry i havent tested so i am now correcting it please run this

Comment: No dice, still -1 ...

Comment: ok.. but now i have run the sh file in my system. where is my mistake if you will let me know that would be very kind..

Comment: hello sir  Radu Rădeanu  will you please tell me what is my mistake in my updated script.. if you tell me i can improve my future script..

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/409191/147044). Also If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.